# CustomValidator textbox required on radiobuttonlist select

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, radiobuttonlist, customvalidator

On my page I have a Radio button list and a textbox.

The textbox is hidden by default then appears if the user clicks yes. Once they click yes then the textbox must be filled in before they can proceed.

I've put in the following code, however it doesn't seem to work at all and when the button is pressed to go to the next page it continues instead of stopping and asking the user to enter something in the box.

```
function Q12iYes() {           
        document.getElementById('txt12i').style.display = "block"
     }
    function Q12iNo() {
        document.getElementById('txt12i').style.display = "none"
    }      


<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtn12" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Yes" onclick="Q12iYes()" /> <asp:ListItem Value="No"  Selected="True" onclick="Q12iNo()" /> 
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
            <br />

    12.i) If &#39;Yes&#39; please provide details<br />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt12i" runat="server" Height="62px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="343px"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />                
            <asp:CustomValidator ID="MyTxtBoxValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt12i" ValidateEmptyText="true" ErrorMessage="Please enter some values into Textbox" 
            ClientValidationFunction="validateMyBtn"  Display="Dynamic"> </asp:CustomValidator>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                  function validateMyBtn(oSrc, args) {
                      var rbtnValue = null;
                      var rbtnList = document.getElementsByName('<%=rbtn12.ClientID %>');
                      var radio = rbtnList[0].getElementsByTagName("input");
                      for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) { if (radio[i].checked) rbtnValue = radio[i].value; }
                      if (rbtnValue == "Yes") { args.IsValid = !(args.Value == "") }
                      else { args.IsValid = true; }
} 
</script> 

<asp:Button ID="btnContinue" runat="server" OnClick="btnContinue_Click" Text="Continue" />
```

I have had a look for how to do it, but nothing I have seen has worked either, or helped me understand where I'm going wrong.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you need a custom validator? Why not use a required field validator? If the input box is not visible the required field validator won't try to validate.

Comment: From all my searches it seemed custom validator was what I needed as I'm using javascript to show and hide the text box when the user selects. I'm trying to find the most effective way of doing it.

Comment: Are you able to use jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `CustomValidator` does not validate empty text by default, so set the [`ValidateEmptyText` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.validateemptytext.aspx):

```
<asp:CustomValidator  ValidateEmptyText="true" ID="MyTxtBoxValidator" runat="server" ...
```

**Edit** The problem was your javascript validation function which works only in IE. Here's a version that works also in other browsers:

```
function validateMyBtn(oSrc, args) {
      var rbtnList = document.getElementsByName('<%=rbtn12.ClientID %>');
      var noClicked = false;
      for (var x = 0; x < rbtnList.length; x++) {
          if (rbtnList[x].checked) {
              noClicked = rbtnList[x].value == "No";
              break;
          }
      }
      if (noClicked) 
          args.IsValid = true;
      else
          args.IsValid = args.Value.trim().length > 0;
}
```

Comment: @saintsfanuk: Overlooked it, because it's important in this context you should have mentioned it explicitely.

Comment: Changed it around and it still makes no difference so I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: @saintsfanuk: I have tested your code and it works as expected. If "Yes" is selected the validator will prevent a postback when the textbox is empty because of your client script: `if (rbtnValue == "Yes") { args.IsValid = !(args.Value == "") }`. But you haven't shown the code of `Q12iYes` and `Q12iNo`.

Comment: It appears it is actually a browser issue, I just tested it on Internet Explorer and it worked but on Chrome and Firefox it just continued to the next page.

Comment: @saintsfanuk: Edited my answer. Your js-function didn't work in FF.

Comment: That has fixed it in Chrome as well, thanks, I'm only just learning javascript. :)

Comment: @saintsfanuk: I've used javascript debuggers to see what happens. For IE you can use Visual Studio, for FF i recommend FireBug. It's better to develop for Firefox first since it's still more standard compliant. If it's working there it's likely that's also working in IE.